# Where would you sit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

Suppose on a summer afternoon, you have two chairs one made of **steel** and other of **wood**. Which one is better to sit on if you prefer colder one, provided they are at the same temperature?
Would your answer vary if both the chairs are now replaced by a **solid wooden box** and a **steel box filled with water**?
We may assume that they are at a temperature higher than body temperature.
I understand that we need to apply the concept of heat transfer but unable to decide between conduction and radiation.

Comment: Isn't "which chair would you prefer?" a rather opinion-based question? Some people might prefer to sit on a warm chair while others might like a colder chair.

Comment: @Jonas I've made a necessary edit. My inquiry is based on qualitative as well as quantitative approach, so I created a practical situation. I necessarily mean which is colder.

Comment: There is still an ambiguity in your question, but there is no need to edit, as your actual intention can be readily inferred. Taken literally your question goes: "a wooden and a steel chair have the same temperature: which one is colder?" Your intended question is of course: "With both chairs heated by the Sun to warmer than body temperature, which one will be the least hot to the touch?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose on a summer afternoon, you have two chairs one made of steel
> and other of wood. Which one is better to sit on if you prefer colder
> one, provided they are at the same temperature?

The minimum requirement for heat to transfer to the skin is the temperature of the chair has to be greater than the temperature of the skin. The normal temperature of the skin is about 33 C (90 F). So the temperature of the chairs must be greater than 33 C (90 F). In addition you may need to take into account the thermal resistance of the clothing, if any, between the skin and the chair, which would require even higher temperatures.

Then how "hot" each of the chairs "feels" depends on (1) the rate of heat transfer from the chair to the skin and (2) whether or not there is sufficient heat available to transfer from the chair to the skin.

The rate of heat transfer from the chair to the skin will depend on temperature difference between the chair and the skin prior to contact, and the thermal conductivity of the chair material. The thermal conductivity of steel (45.3 w/m.K) is much greater than that of wood (0.12-0.04 w/m.K).

Regarding the thermal energy available from each chair, assuming they are constructed identically except for material, that will depend on their volumetric heat capacities, which is the product of the specific heat and density of the material, or $C=\rho c$. Although the specific heat of wood is greater than steel the density of steel is greater than wood, so the volumetric heat capacities will be roughly comparable. To put some typical numbers on this:

For wood

c=1.76 KJ/kg$^o$C

$\rho$ = 1500 kg/m$^3$

$C$=2640 kJ/m$^3$

For steel

c=0.461 KJ/kg$^o$C

$\rho$ = 7500 kg/m$^3$

$C$=3458 kJ/m$^3$

So the volumetric heat capacities are comparable. It is only if the thickness (volume) of the chair seat is extremely thin, will the difference in volumetric heat capacity possibly make a difference. It's like aluminum foil. It has high thermal conductivity but it is so thin that its volumetric heat capacity is so low you can take foil directly out of a very hot oven without it feeling hot.

Bottom line, given the above, the steel chair will feel warmer, and the wood chair will feel cooler.

> Would your answer vary if both the chairs are now replaced by a solid
> wooden box and a steel box filled with water?

The thermal conductivity of water (0.6 w/m K) is more than six times greater than the thermal conductivity of wood but it is still far lower than the thermal conductivity of steel alone. And now that the "chairs" are solid boxes, there should be more than enough available heat from both.

> I understand that we need to apply the concept of heat transfer but
> unable to decide between conduction and radiation.

Since heat transfer is is due to direct contact between the person and the chair, the transfer mechanism would be conduction. Moreover, heat transfer by radiation only becomes significant when the temperatures are very high since heat transfer by radiation is proportional to temperature raised to the fourth power.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So can radiation be considered as least effective form of heat transfer at lower temperature?
And **most** effective at higher temperatures?

Comment: @JaswanthNaga The most efficient method of heat transfer is conduction, followed by convection and radiation. For a primer on the differences see https://www.g9toengineering.com/resources/heattransfer.htm

Answer (score 2):

Wooden chair in both case because being a bad conductor wood will absorb less amount of heat and most will be reflected.
In second case again due to conduction more and more heat will pass to water and finally the steel box become heated, but the wooden box not absorb heat and there is no chance to pass it to water.

Answer (score 2):

What you feel is not temperature $T$. What you feel is heat transfer $Q$. The chair that feels colder will be the one with a lower **thermal conductivity** and lower **heat capacity**.

- **Thermal conductivity** $\kappa$ because a higher value means heat transferred faster into your body. $$\dot Q =\kappa A \nabla T$$
- **Heat capacity** $c$ because a higher value means plenty of heat to transfer into your body. The heat transfer will namely only stop when the temperature of the chair itself is lowered, $$Q=cm\Delta T. $$

Together these two parameters control how much thermal energy that is transferred into your body over the duration that you are sitting on the chair. On both parameters, metals like steel are typically higher - so you would pick the wooden chair.

Radiation is most commenly much, much lower than conduction. So it isn't relevant. Conduction is the primary heat transfer mechanism as long as the temperatures are not very, very high (in which case the objects might burn or melt).